# sendKey not working for android.view.View class

Tags: appium

My appium version is 1.4.16.1.

There is an object on the screen (a passcode field) where I want to pass some text into it.
Below are the details of it:
index 1
text 
resource-id FLD_PASSCODE_item
class android.view.View
package glb.farms.mobile
content-desc Passcode

I am using the following code:
 driver_and.findElement(By.xpath("//android.view.View[@resource-id='FLD_PASSCODE_item']")).sendKeys("1234");

I am observing that the sendKeys feature is not working. Can anybody help here please.

Comment: try this .. driver_and.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='FLD_PASSCODE_item']")).sendKeys("1234");

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
driver_and.findElementById("FLD_PASSCODE_item").sendKeys("1234");
```

Comment: Ok cool.. If it works can pick this as the best answer so that it would help others too